# Trouble linking BREW objects under WinARM4.1x

Tags: linker, arm, brew-framework, brewmp

I'm trying to use WinARM 4.1.1 to compile and link object files for a BREW project. I got started using this page: http://brew.wardco.com/.

First thing to note is that I have this successfully working under the GNUDE tool chain. When I switched over to WinARM, I initially got it to work till I noticed that I had -Lc:/***gnude***/arm-elf/lib instead of -Lc:/***WinARM***/arm-elf/lib in my linker library path. I obviously don't want to have both systems in place in my environment. Using the WinARM library path causes me to get the following linker errors:

```
c:/WinARM/arm-elf/lib\libsupc++.a(eh_personality.o): In function `read_encoded_value_with_base':
c:/winarms/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/unwind-pe.h:259: undefined reference to `abort'
c:/WinARM/arm-elf/lib\libsupc++.a(eh_personality.o): In function `base_of_encoded_value':
c:/winarms/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/unwind-pe.h:122: undefined reference to `abort'
c:/winarms/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/unwind-pe.h:122: undefined reference to `abort'
c:/WinARM/arm-elf/lib\libsupc++.a(eh_personality.o): In function `size_of_encoded_value':
c:/winarms/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/unwind-pe.h:90: undefined reference to `abort'
c:/WinARM/arm-elf/lib\libsupc++.a(eh_terminate.o): In function `__cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)())':
../../../../../gcc-4.1.1/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:44: undefined reference to `abort'
c:/WinARM/arm-elf/lib\libsupc++.a(eh_terminate.o):../../../../../gcc-4.1.1/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:46: more undefined references to `abort' follow
c:/WinARM/arm-elf/lib\libc.a(fopen.o): In function `_fopen_r':
fopen.c:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `_open_r'
c:/WinARM/arm-elf/lib\libc.a(freer.o): In function `_malloc_trim_r':
mallocr.c:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `_sbrk_r'
mallocr.c:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `_sbrk_r'
mallocr.c:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `_sbrk_r'
c:/WinARM/arm-elf/lib\libc.a(fseek.o): In function `_fseek_r':
fseek.c:(.text+0x158): undefined reference to `_fstat_r'
fseek.c:(.text+0x1b0): undefined reference to `_fstat_r'
c:/WinARM/arm-elf/lib\libc.a(makebuf.o): In function `__smakebuf':
makebuf.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `_fstat_r'
makebuf.c:(.text+0x110): undefined reference to `isatty'
c:/WinARM/arm-elf/lib\libc.a(mallocr.o): In function `_malloc_r':
mallocr.c:(.text+0x424): undefined reference to `_sbrk_r'
mallocr.c:(.text+0x4cc): undefined reference to `_sbrk_r'
c:/WinARM/arm-elf/lib\libc.a(stdio.o): In function `__sclose':
stdio.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `_close_r'
c:/WinARM/arm-elf/lib\libc.a(stdio.o): In function `__sseek':
stdio.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `_lseek_r'
c:/WinARM/arm-elf/lib\libc.a(stdio.o): In function `__swrite':
stdio.c:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `_lseek_r'
stdio.c:(.text+0xac): undefined reference to `_write_r'
c:/WinARM/arm-elf/lib\libc.a(stdio.o): In function `__sread':
stdio.c:(.text+0xd0): undefined reference to `_read_r'
c:/WinARM/arm-elf/lib\libc.a(syswrite.o): In function `write':
syswrite.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `_write_r'
C:\WinARM/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.1.1/\libgcc.a(unwind-sjlj.o): In function `_Unwind_RaiseException_Phase2':
../../../gcc-4.1.1/gcc/unwind.inc:75: undefined reference to `abort'
C:\WinARM/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.1.1/\libgcc.a(unwind-sjlj.o): In function `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume':
../../../gcc-4.1.1/gcc/unwind.inc:238: undefined reference to `abort'
C:\WinARM/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.1.1/\libgcc.a(unwind-sjlj.o): In function `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume_or_Rethrow':
../../../gcc-4.1.1/gcc/unwind.inc:263: undefined reference to `abort'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\WinARM\bin\arm-elf-ld.EXE' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

I am not sure how to approach solving this; it appears that I am simply missing a path somewhere, but which path? I notice there are "c:\winarms\gcc-4.1.1..." 'paths' listed... this not a location on my computer. Is it a library reference?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried c:\WinARM\lib\gcc\arm-elf\4.1.1 ?  Your lib path could also depend on what kind of instruction set you are using.  I use something like c:\blahblah\WinARM\lib\gcc\arm-elf\4.1.1\thumb because I build most of my sources into the thumb instruction set.